# Android Implement Loading Screen

Tags: android

My app has a number of background tasks it needs to complete so I'm looking into doing a loading screen.

I think the route that I want to do is on entering my `MainActivity` set the content view to `activity_loading` and then start an `AsyncTask` that shows a progress bar and updates it as each of the tasks complete.

Then in the `onPostExecute` I set the content view to `activity_main`, while I still have all of my data and such in my activity.

Is this the best way to do it? Or is there a better route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `setContentView()` more with single activity. For your requirement, you should use **Splash Screen** when your activity is opened by user. You can display this for customized time i.e. 5000 ms, 7000 ms etc

While user is watching **Splash Screen**, we will start `AsyncTask` and start processing or loading of data. You can terminate **Spash Screen** from `onPostExecute()` and show your `content view` or `fragment`

Sample code from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) :

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    // start your AsyncTask here
    new FetchData().execute();

}


 private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // make calls to http network     

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         // fetch data here
    }

    @Override
    protected Void onPostExecute(Void... arg0) {
         // change contentview
         // we call handler to show our main content and close this splash screen
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);    // delay is good so that wrapping up of data is done
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it by including the loading layout inside a `FrameLayout` of your activity and then toggling its visibility. Calling `setContentView` seems a bit unnecessary. Also ofc make sure your `FrameLayout` is the last child view in your `Activity`'s layout. It'd become easier to manage this way as you'd know all your activities with `AsyncTask` will have a loading layout that can get toggled.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setContentView()` more than one is a **bad** practice.
You should rather show `ProgressBar` as you are showing and than :

- If you are using a `ListView` or a `GridView`, you should rather call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` to reflect the changes.
- You should try using Fragments to dynamically replace the loading portion of the screen with the dynamic `Fragment`.

Comment: Great idea - I'll give that one a go